# how can I convert slow motion video into normal speed without losing fps or audio sample rate?

Tags: video, audio, mp4, framerate

I want to download a slow-motion video playlist (with the frame rate of the videos being either 480 fps or 1000 fps.) and be able to speed up the videos at least 16x without losing the frame rate or sample rate. So, if anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Either I'm not understanding you right or you are asking for something isn't possible. If you speed the video up from 480 fps to 30 fps, you have to discard some frames. Or are you asking if there is a way to play the 480 fps video at that frame rate? That would require a display that can handle that frame rate and those are not commercially available yet.

Comment: i think he's saying he wants a 10 second 500fps clip to become a 5 second 1000fps clip, for example. But i also suspect this might be a 24fps video of a 500fps slow-motion capture, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Hello! Yes, what Sirex said is correct, it would be more convenient to be able to watch a slow-motion video sped up to normal speed on a 60 fps monitor. But then when I need it slowed down, I could use software or something to view it in slow motion.

Answer (score 1):

This is sadly not possible.
You could theoretically have a video with effectivly 500 FPS, but that won't play on any device.

That's why cameras generally record to a project frame rate (Normaly 24, 25 or 30 FPS) and just stretch out the video.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But when you said, "You could theoretically have a video with effectively 500 FPS, but that won't play on any device." Do you mean that the device that tries to play it will crash or that it won't play higher than 60 fps? I'm fine with it only playing 60 fps if that's the case...

Comment: @TheRedstoneGuy It won't crash the device, at least not any modern and decent device. But it will lag. As the player will try to read all frames. Stick to the standart and just let it play at frame by frame speed

Answer (score 0):

This is a contradiction.

If you want to change the frame rate speeding up you have to change the frame rate.

You could try to playback a video at 16,000 fps... Why would you need to playback a video to 16,000 fps if no human or living being could notice the difference to let's say 120 fps?

You also need a monster of a computer to playback that among other technical problems.

---

> But then when I need it slowed down, I could use software or something to view it in slow motion

Ok, so have two versions of it, one converted to normal speed and the original.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a 500 fps video or something but would the computer crash trying to play the file even with a 60 fps monitor?